# PyQt5 Fill the table

Tags: python, pyqt5

I need to randomly fill out the table. I did this using the for loop. But filling occurs only at the last iteration. That is, only one cell is repainted. This is a function:

```
def generateTable(self):
    count = random.randint(10, 20)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    predator = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0))
    predator.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    herbivore = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
    herbivore.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    for i in range(count):
        x = random.randint(0, 19)
        y = random.randint(0, 29)
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            item.setBackground(predator)
            self.BoardTable.setItem(x, y, item)
        else:
            item.setBackground(herbivore)
            self.BoardTable.setItem(x, y, item)
```

I think there is not enough of an important line in the loop.

Comment: And what is `self.BoardTable`?

Comment: this is Table Widget

Answer (score 0):

I had to put QTableWidgetItem in the loop:

```
    def generateTable(self):
    count = random.randint(10, 20)
    predator = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
    predator.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    herbivore = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0))
    herbivore.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    for i in range(count):
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        x = random.randint(0, 19)
        y = random.randint(0, 29)
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            item.setBackground(predator)
            self.BoardTable.setItem(x, y, item)
        else:
            item.setBackground(herbivore)
            self.BoardTable.setItem(x, y, item)
```